# List API get all items limited to 100 rows

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-online

When doing a GET call to the List API from JavaScript: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items" the results returned are limited to 100 rows.

Is there any way to return more rows in the result, like return 1000 rows instead? Or do I have to resort to paging?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The limit is due to server-driven paging. It protects against developers inadvertently making a request that returns large result sets.

You can use $top if you really want a large result set to be returned. Otherwise you can get the results a page at a time by checking __next. If it has a value, it contains the url that will return the next set of items. If it's null, you've hit the end of the result set.

```
function callToHostWeb() {
    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text("");

    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var appUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    var scriptbase = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    var url = appUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Order Details')/Items?$select=Title&@target='" + hostUrl + "'";
    jQuery.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getOrderDetails);

    function getOrderDetails() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appUrl);
        executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.body);
                    message.append(String.format("Retrieved {0} items", response.d.results.length));
                    message.append("<br/>");

                    if (response.d.__next) {
                        url = response.d.__next;
                        getOrderDetails();
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
            document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that $top is the one you should be going after. $limit does not work for me in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: $limit didn't work for me either

Comment: Good answer +1. However your callback on success may need to work on all results. See my answer for handling that case.

Comment: i there any way to get all data of list using REST. Because i dont want to give static limit to top. i  am making graph from that records . so i want all data of list.

Comment: what if we want to use filter like `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$filter=ColumnName eq 'abc'&$top=1000"`. Where we have more than 5000 items having value 'abc' in the `ColumnName`. Will it work?

Comment: @Harsh, it wont work. Since it hits the threshold limit. Best option is to go for REST Search API and get the items.

Answer (score 33):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$top=1000
```

Comment: The problem with $top is that you do a single ajax call with potentially a lot of results in your response. This may cause performance issues.

Answer (score 14):

the "$limit=" option above does NOT work. however, the $top= does.

Comment: The problem with $top is that you do a single ajax call with potentially a lot of results in your response. This may cause performance issues.

Answer (score 7):

The option of querying items with $top is not advisable for performance reasons and impact on the network traffic.

The best option is recursion. **Note**: Normally you have a callback on success and you may have to work on all items: in that case you need to concat all results before executing the callback. Also you may need a check on complete callback. The following example address this use case:

```
function GetAllItems (ListGuid, Query, OnSuccess, OnComplete) {

    function GetItems() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                results = results.concat(data.d.results);
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    url = data.d.__next;
                    GetItems();
                }
                else {
                    nonext = true;
                    if (typeof OnSuccess != 'undefined') OnSuccess(results);
                }
            },
            error: SPUtils.onQueryFailed,
            complete: function () {
                if (typeof OnComplete != 'undefined' && nonext) {
                    OnComplete();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var nonext = false;
    var results = [];
    var url = LMS.WebApi + "/lists(guid'" + ListGuid + "')/items?" + Query;
    GetItems();
}
```

Comment: Just a note; `data.d.__next` will be `data['odata.nextLink']` if you are using `odata=nometadata` , verbose should not be used imo unless there is a reason for it.

Comment: @AndersAune good point, in most scenarios **nometadata** provides all we need with minimal payload.

Comment: Clean code!!! ++

Comment: I disagree - if you literally want all of the items, a single request is more performant and has less network overhead. If you're display items to a user, however, you'll want to use paging.  If you're doing a "type-ahead" dropdown, you'll want to limit.  But if you actually want all items, request all items in a single request.

Comment: also, this isn't recursion

Answer (score 5):

100 items is the [default limit](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-measuring-performance-on-the-jslink-property-in-sharepoint-2013) Please use `$top` in your request:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$top=1000
```

Comment: $limit does not work

Answer (score -2):

You need to be sure to have `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE` for this to work in 2013.