# Web/Lists/GetByTitle returns only 100 rows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest

I am facing a problem in `Web/Lists/GetByTitle` method. By default, it returns only 100 rows.

I changed it to
 `http://sitename/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('list')/Items?$top=300`.

When I hit this URL into the browser, I am getting all records but when I put this in the workflow as a step, it fails.

Can anybody please let me know what else I need to change to make it work in the workflow as well.

Comment: Log the error message and see the error details

Comment: Refer [Get more  SP items using REST](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/list-api-get-all-items-limited-to-100-rows). It talks about the same issue

Comment: which property u want to get from all those items??

Comment: Ideally these REST URLs are supposed to work. Mostly Workflows will be focusing an item than items. So for what you are fetching huge number of item?

Comment: I am getting the same issue, did u resolved? pls suggest

Answer (score 1):

Used top filter to get data

Example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$top=1000   //returns only 1000 records
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it might be a response size issue. Can you please try to limit the records to 10 and see if it works.
I can help you reading all records in chunks if limited number is working.
or
You can log error by data/responseText.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is due to server-driven paging. It protects against developers inadvertently making a request that returns large result sets. Hence by default it will return only 100 items until you explicitly specify number of items to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The sharepoint rest apis by default returns 100 rows per query if you haven't provided any $top parameter.

you can overcome this problem by

1. recursive rest api calls.
2. using $top parameter.