# JSOM or Rest Api for querying list with more than 5000 entries with query conditions

Tags: office-365, csom, jsom

I am trying to get items from the workflow history list,  which has more than 5000 entries using the below code

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Workflow history");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-100' /></Value></Leq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++) {
                var pageItem = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
                console.log(pageItem.get_fieldValues()['Title']);
            }

        },
        function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

This works for lists with items less than 5000. Is there a way to make this work for workflow history list?

P.S:
I also tried rest api like this

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow History')/items?$filter=(Created ge datetime'2017-10-01T07:00:00.000Z')&$top=5000
```

I got the below error. I was trying to get items created after Oct 2017

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator.

Comment: In case you want to try REST API.  Refer this link for querying more than 5000 items from list - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library/217451#217451

Comment: will I be able to use filter? like I tried to get items created after August 2017, but it was throwing error

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to `index columns` which can be grouped by in REST call(i.e. Filter based on those index columns until you get a result which is less than 5000).

let say you have 10,000 items in a Products list. When you filter it with `Product(indexed column)` you get 7000, again you need to filter it with `Discount(indexcolumn)` now the final result will be 3000 items

```
https://webapp.site.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items?$filter=Product eq 'iPhone' and Discount_x0020_Type eq 'xMas'
```

Detailed MSDN documentation for indexing. [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-index-to-a-SharePoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query a list if the coloumns you are using are indexed. I don't know if that also work for the filter option.

Here's an example (Post request) on a query on a list (replace #1 with the guid of your list):

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'#1')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">test</Value></Eq></Where></Query></view>"}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the field in Lager list which is more than 5000 items, if you want to filter the field in Rest API, you need to make this field indexing:
[REST api querying large list](https://srinivasananand.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/rest-api-querying-large-list/)