# SharePoint Online REST API returns empty results if a folder contains more than 5000 files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

I noticed that SharePoint is returning empty results if a folder contains more than 5000 files. I am using the following URL. /_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl')/Files. Is there a way to retrieve all the possible documents with the same URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way SharePoint rest API can return more than 5k result in a single call. you have to use batch request or apply pagination or do loop but it will have multiple rest call. you can have look below code for reference

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentList')/items?$select=customerID&$top=1000";
    var response = response || [];  // this variable is used for storing list items
    function GetListItems(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },
            success: function(data){
                response = response.concat(data.d.results);
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    url = data.d.__next;
                    GetListItems();
                }
                $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                    arrayCustomerID[index] = item.customerID;
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
            }
        });
    }
```

ref :[Rest to read more than 5000 items from document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library)