# CAML query returns different data

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, spfx, caml, list-view-threshold

I created a CAML query that I need to use as a workaround for REST API and the 5k threshold limit: However when I was testing it using the SharePoint CAML Query Helper Online, it returns the correct result which is one record.

But when I use it in my code, it returns a lot of records that do not fit the filters I have used.

[image]

This is my CAML query which returns the correct data:

```
<Query><Where><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And>
   <Eq><FieldRef Name="IsCurrentBooking" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq><Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='NG_Venues' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='LookupMulti'>${adjVenue}</Value></Eq></And>
   <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
   <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
   <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
   <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
   <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Leq></And>
   <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Geq></And>
   <Neq><FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Cancelled</Value></Neq></And><Neq>
   <FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Rejected</Value></Neq></And></Where>
   <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
</Query>
```

and I use it like:

```
let start=moment(startDate).toISOString();
    let end=moment(endDate).toISOString();

     items.forEach(v=> {
                let adjVenue= v.AdjVenue.ID;
                let message= v.AlertMessage;
                console.log('adjVenue: ',adjVenue);
                console.log('message: ',message);


                const xml = `<Query><Where><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And>
                          <Eq><FieldRef Name="IsCurrentBooking" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq><Eq>
                          <FieldRef Name='NG_Venues' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='LookupMulti'>${adjVenue}</Value></Eq></And>
                          <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
                          <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
                          <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
                          <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
                          <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Leq></And>
                          <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Geq></And>
                          <Neq><FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Cancelled</Value></Neq></And><Neq>
                          <FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Rejected</Value></Neq></And></Where>
                          <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit></Query> `;
                const dataFilter: CamlQuery = {
                ViewXml: xml,
                };

                prom.push(dataFilter);

              });
              let promises = prom.map(df => {
                  return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EventBookingDetails").getItemsByCAMLQuery(df);
                });
              return Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                let rslt;
                res.forEach(r => {
                  console.log(r, r.length);
                  if(r.length > 0){
                    console.log(r[0]);
                    console.log(items);
                    let adjItem;
                    if(r[0].NG_Venues[0].ID){
                      adjItem = items.filter(i => i.AdjVenue.ID == r[0].NG_Venues[0].ID);
                    } else {
                      adjItem = items.filter(i => i.AdjVenue.ID == r[0].NG_VenuesId);
                    }

                    console.log(adjItem);
                    result.result=true;
                    result.message=adjItem[0].AlertMessage;
                    rslt=result;
                  } else {
                    result.result = false;
                    result.message = "";
                    rslt=result;
                  }
                });            
                return rslt;
              });
```

Also, Everytime I add `IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'`, results are also wrong.

Comment: In case you want to use REST API to get more than 5000 records. Refer this solution -  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library

Comment: hi @RohitWaghela not sure how that would apply to what i need. what the previous code is using pnp sp js

Comment: Hi I thnik,you have to add <view> at the beginning of the xml and </view> at the end

Comment: Hi @myomyo tried adding <View> but it returned a lot of unneeded items as well.

Comment: @PageF.P.T change the positon of "<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>" after <Query>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @myomyo for giving the idea. i have changed the caml query to include query and view:

```
<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit><Query><Where><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And><And>
                      <Eq><FieldRef Name="IsCurrentBooking" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq><Eq>
                      <FieldRef Name='NG_Venues' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='LookupMulti'>${adjVenue}</Value></Eq></And>
                      <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
                      <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
                      <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Geq></And>
                      <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Leq></And>
                      <Leq><FieldRef Name="NG_EventDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${start}</Value></Leq></And>
                      <Geq><FieldRef Name="NG_EndDate" /><Value Type="DateTime">${end}</Value></Geq></And>
                      <Neq><FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Cancelled</Value></Neq></And><Neq>
                      <FieldRef Name="NG_BookingStatus" /><Value Type="Text">Rejected</Value></Neq></And></Where>
                      </Query></View>
```