# REST filtering large list by lookup field value

Tags: search, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, error, lookup-column

Is it possible to search in large list by lookup filed value with 'substringof'
like:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Obchodné Prípady')/items?$select=*,Investor/Title&$expand=Investor/ID&$top=100&$filter=substringof('test', Investor/Title)&$orderby=Created desc
```

While the data in list was below 5000 items it worked fine.

Searching in Title or other columns is working after adding indexes,
but searching in lookup field 'Investor/Title' gets threshold limit error, even the indexes are created.

The number of items in the list where lookup points is below 5000.

Comment: You can check this answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library

Comment: Thanks, it could help, but it looks like litle dirty solution.
For my case would be better to crate a another filed in list, where we copy the Tilte form the lookup automaticaly. Then use this field for searching

Comment: Using paging, a dirty solution? 
But a solution where you duplicate data is not dirty?

Comment: The search crawl is not duplicating the data?  Not the paging is dirty, but the method that you have to search in parts of list, and putting it togeher.
I was wondering there is a easy solution, like reindexing the columns or something that.