# Limit and filter List

Tags: rest, filter, api

I have a list with more then 100 rows, so I added limit to the url.

I have two questions:

1. How can I set it to not limit with no write a specific number (like 1000)?
2. How can I add a filter to the list?
3. I tried to do

   `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$limit=1000&$filter= status eq 'ok'`

   but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

<s>To return unlimited results, just drop the `$limit=1000` from the query.</s>

EDIT: Indeed SharePoint by default returns 100 items of the list. The correct way to return a bigger subset of items would be to use `$top=` in the query. However, note that this default value of 100 is implemented most importantly for performance reasons. This means that it would be advised to implement *paging* for your returned items showing e.g. 100, 200 or 1000 items per page. This has been discussed e.g. here: [List API get all items limited to 100 rows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/list-api-get-all-items-limited-to-100-rows)

To properly filter the return, the syntax needs to be `$filter=<column> <operator> '<value>'`. Pay attention to the spaces! So in your cases the query would be:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$top=1000&$filter=status eq 'ok'
```

Comment: If I drop it, It's return only 100 items...

Comment: @uriel you are correct, I edited the answer.

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: @uriel do you actually have a column by the name `status` in your list? Are there list items which actually have a value of `ok` in the `status` field?