# Cascading limitation on number of items

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have implemented cascading in SharePoint online. The problem is that it is not populating items when the number of items is more than 100.

I am using below code for cascading.

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "BG",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "BUSINESS_GROUP",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "COE",
    parentColumn: "BG",
    childColumn: "COE",
    debug: true
  });
```

Is there any way to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without actually knowing anything about your implementation. Any hard-coded 100 limit shouldn't exist, but sure it will depend on how the cascading has been created.

Comment: This might be due to SharePoint web services limiting to 100 results when getting items.  See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/74777/8992

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use `SPComplexToSimpleDropdown` function for the column contains more than 100 item,
 
 check the below example:

```
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({  
    columnName: "COE", // the colums name which contains more than 100 item
    completefunc: null,
    debug: true
});

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "BG",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "BUSINESS_GROUP",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "COE",
    parentColumn: "BG",
    childColumn: "COE",
    simpleChild: true,
    debug: true
  });
```